# How to get UID of an active directory user from Jxplorer

Tags: active-directory, ldap, uid

I have connected to an active directory using jxplorer by providing the cn and password of a user. i want to get the UID of that user. How can i get it from the jxplorer or from other source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory does not include this attribute in the schema by default. If you need it, you can install the component of [Windows Services for UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX) that modifies the schema.

Comment: And you have to maintain values in it on your own.